# BPMN XOR Gateway within parallel gateway allowed?

Tags: bpmn

Does someone know if the following BPMN model is correct?
I'm not sure here because of XOR gateway within the parallel gateway.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found the solution.
The example above is not correct. 
Instead of the normal end event, a termination event must be used. This event terminates the whole process immediately and removes all other tokens.

This would be the correct solution:

[image]